# Soft 404 error: PHP not sending 404 header

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

I have a php script when page is not found in database, I send http headers `404 not found`, instead php is sending HTTP 200. Google webmaster tools shows its a soft 404 error.

```
<?php 
if (mysql_num_rows($rs_press) == 0) {

    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    include('404.shtml');
    exit;

}
?>
```

and the HTTP response for the page in GMT is quite strange shows HTTP 200 OK. Why is PHP sending 200, instead of 404 error as this is quite strange?.

[image]

The if code works correct but only the 404 headers are not sent. Here is the output of the page..

[image]

How do i fix?
I am running PHP 5.6/Apache on a Dedicated server, Smarty with **SSL activated**.

Comment: Do you access the if clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP [header() function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) actually takes 3 arguments:

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

Try changing your code to this:

```
<?php 
if (mysql_num_rows($rs_press) == 0) {

    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found", true, 404);
    include('404.shtml');
    exit;

}
?>
```

Alternatively, you could try using the [http_response_code()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) function.

Comment: Thanks, i tried, both http_response_code() and above not not working. If i take out include(404.shml) the page is blank.

Comment: @pbu I just tested the same header() call as above on my local server, and it did indeed return a 404 header. Does it give you a 404 header when you remove the include?

Comment: It shows white blank page when i remove the include. Probably the headers are sent previously before..

Comment: @pbu Yes, but in the **HTTP header**, is it returning 404 when you remove the include?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, exactly. It shouldn't behave any different on https. I would check your apache logs and your php logs to see if it's giving any error or warning messages. If you see something interesting in the logs, you can add it to your question and I'll try to help resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159175/discussion-between-pbu-and-gogeta70).